# Matching a string with a special character in Perl

Tags: perl

I am having trouble with matching a string with a dollar sign (`$`) in it.

Here is my code:

```
if (index($ln, '$COMB') != -1) 
{
    [do some stuff]
}
```

I have tried `'\$COMB'`, `'\\$COMB'` and `'\\\$COMB'`

I need to match the exact string, `$COMB`. The problem is that my code also matches : `$[some other stuff]COMB`. Which is not what I want.

Comment: Actually, that's not the problem. Something else in my code was misleading my debugging.

Comment: I would delete this post if I could find the button for that.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `index` checks if a string is *contained in* another. It won't find `$COMB` in `$..COMB` as you claim, but it would find it in `...$COMB...`.

If you want to check if a string is *the same as* another, use `eq`.

```
$ln eq '$COMB'
```

For example,

```
$ perl -e'
   CORE::say qq{"$_" is }.( $_ eq "abc" ? "equal" : "not equal" ).qq{ to "abc"}
      for qw( abc abcdef def );
'
"abc" is equal to "abc"
"abcdef" is not equal to "abc"
"def" is not equal to "abc"
```